# windows 8 metro app facebook integration

Tags: facebook-graph-api, windows-8, facebook-c#-sdk

When I register my app on the facebook developers site there are options on how your app integrates with Facebook.  Which one do I choose for windows 8 metro style app?  I only see "website with facebook login", "App on Facebook", "Mobile Web", Native iOS App, "Native Android App", and "Page Tab".  I tried picked "Website with Facebook Login", but in that case what do I fill in for the Site URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site url is only required if you set the `redirect_uri` to something else besides `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`.